# Conditionally drop labels

Tags: prometheus

I would like to drop a label but only from a specific series.
From the doc I can see that the action needed is labeldrop.

My starting point is something like

```yaml
    - action: replace
      source_labels: [__name__, url_rule]
      regex: 'test_.+;(.+)'
      target_label: path
    - action: labeldrop
      regex: 'url_rule'
```

How can I ensure that the second action will only drop the url_rule label from metrics starting by test_ (like in the first action)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability for conditional label removal via `action: labeldrop`. This action is applied unconditionally to every label of every metric. But you can use the following workaround for removal of `url_rule` label from metrics with names starting from `test_`:

```yaml
- source_labels: [__name__, url_rule]
  regex: "test_.+;.+"
  replacement: ""
  target_label: url_rule
```

It just sets an empty value to `url_rule` label for metrics with names starting from `test_` prefix. Then Prometheus drops labels with empty values after the relabeling.

P.S. The relabeling rule can be simplified with `if` condition when using VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on:

```yaml
- if: "{__name__=~'test_.+'}"
  action: labeldrop
  regex: url_rule
```

See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling-enhancements) for details.